# How to make a copy of a single sheet and save it to a folder in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a problem I have where I have around 20 different sheets that I'm working with. With each sheet, I've created a button that says "export" that will save the single sheet (if I can figure it out) to a specified folder. I then have a script that clears the sheet so that it's new again (That works great!). I'm using this in our brewery to take the date of beers in tanks and when the tank is empty, the data is then stored for future reference.

So, as of now, the code work pretty much as I'd like it to, but it's saving all of the sheets as one file and now only exporting the sheet that I'm currently looking at.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried a couple different codes and this is as close as I've gotten.

```
function createCopy() {
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A29").getValue();
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<<google drive folder>>");
  DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(myValue,destinationFolder);
}
```

If all goes well, it will save a single sheet to my destination folder.

Comment: It's unclear to me why this was downvoted? Max clearly provided what he tried so far, what his expected result and his actual result is.

Comment: I appreciate the support. This is my first post so I'm not completely clear of the format. After spending all morning with this, I'm very much looking forward to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way (or rather, I don't know of one) to copy just one sheet out of the spreadsheet, except by creating a new spreadsheet, copying your sheet there and moving that new spreadsheet in your folder. Makes your code a bit longer, but I believe this should do the trick:

```
function createCopy() {
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A29").getValue();
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<<google drive folder>>");
  var backupSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create(myValue).getId();
  var backupSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(backupSpreadsheetId);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().copyTo(backupSpreadsheet);
  backupSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(backupSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var backupFile = DriveApp.getFileById(backupSpreadsheetId)                                                             
  var currentParent = backupFile.getParents().next();
  destinationFolder.addFile(backupFile);
  currentParent.removeFile(backupFile);
}
```

Comment: Epic! That worked perfectly! Thank you very much for this. A huge weight off of my shoulders. What a great community!